# Sendgrid - Email Formatting

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am new to API's. I have created an API using curl command:

```sh
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY>>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"john.doe@example.com","name":"John Doe"}],"subject":"Hello, World!"}],"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}],"from":{"email":"sam.smith@example.com","name":"Sam Smith"},"reply_to":{"email":"sam.smith@example.com","name":"Sam Smith"}}'
```

It worked perfectly for me and it sent out the email.

I was wondering, how do I send an email body with html tags and images. Sorry if this is a basic question and asking here.

Answer (score 1):

In your data that you are sending to the API, you have

```
"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}]
```

This is sending your plain text email. To add HTML to this you can add another object to that array with the `"type": "text/html"`.

```
"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}, { "type": "text/html", value: "<h1>Heya!</h1>" }]
```

Sending images requires you to base 64 encode the contents of the image and add it to the `"attachments"` key within the JSON data, along with the filename, content type and content ID if you want to use it for embedding in the email.

```
"content": [ ... ], "attachments": [{ "content": BASE64_ENCODED_STRING, "type": "image/jpeg", "filename": "catsinhats.jpeg" }]
```

This blog post has more specifically on [how to embed images in emails](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/).